# Typedef expecting ';' before ""

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, typedef

(Don't bust my nuts about using std::auto_ptr<>, this isn't my code, it's auto-generated. I'm just trying to interface to it.)

I have a function with the following signature:

`std::auto_ptr<T> gFunction(const std::string&, int, const int&)`

This function is overloaded like 588 times so assigning it to a `boost::function` is ambiguous. Ok, fine, I'll just recast it and then assign it.

It's cumbersome to type like this:

`std::auto_ptr<T> (*func)(const std::string&, int, const int&) = &gFunction`

I want to `typedef` this so I can use it in the following way:

`function_type func = &gFunction`

So I tried to typedef

`typedef std::auto_ptr<T>(*funct)(const std::string&, int, const int&) function_type;`

But my typedef is returning a `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘function_type’`

Any ideas? I'm probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it this way:

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<T>(*function_type)(const std::string&, int, const int&);
```

Also keep in mind, that `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++11. If you can, you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

In C++11 you can also use the [`std::add_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_pointer) type trait to add a pointer to a function type (if that makes it more intuitive to you):

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef typename std::add_pointer<
    std::shared_ptr<T>(const std::string&, int, const int&)
    >::type function_type;
```

Also, [as mentioned by Mike Seymour in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699655/typedef-expecting-before/16699675?noredirect=1#comment24036908_16699675), you may consider defining the type alias `function_type` as a *function type* (as the name would suggest), rather than making it a function pointer type (just drop the `*` to do that).

Comment: Although `function_type` is a slightly misleading name for a function-pointer type. I'd drop the `*` to make it a function type, and use it as `function_type * func = &gFunction;`. That also means you can use it to declare the 588 overloads, `function_type gFunction;`.

Comment: Thanks for the `auto_ptr` advice. I needed that.

Also, your fix worked wonderfully.

Comment: I don't have access to `C++11` :(

Comment: @TylerJandreau: OK, glad I could help at least in part

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for declaring a typedef should mimic a variable declaration. Syntactically, they are the same except you prefix it with 'typedef'. Semantically the declared names form very different purposes(one makes a variable, one makes a type)

just as you typed the following to declared a variable

```
std::auto_ptr<T> (*func)(const std::string&, int, const int&);
```

you can make this a typedef just be adding a "typedef" to the front

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<T> (*func)(const std::string&, int, const int&);
```

Comment: Good answer, @Jake, thanks for the quick response. I'm not familiar with `typedef` syntax.